# Cannot use networking but network interfaces exist in virtual machine

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, network-interface, kvm, qemu

I am trying to get a virtual machine with user-mode networking setup, but no networking seems to work, not even ping localhost or wget localhost. Loopback "lo", and an ethernet "eth0" devices exist when I run ifconfig, however neither one has an IP address.

For context, I am following this guide: https://mergeboard.com/blog/2-qemu-microvm-docker/

Here is the command I use to start the VM:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 \
-M microvm,x-option-roms=off,isa-serial=off,rtc=off \
-no-acpi \
-enable-kvm \
-cpu host \
-nodefaults \
-no-user-config \
-nographic \
-no-reboot \
-device virtio-serial-device \
-chardev stdio,id=virtiocon0 \
-device virtconsole,chardev=virtiocon0 \
-drive id=root,file=alpine.qcow2,format=qcow2,if=none \
-device virtio-blk-device,drive=root \
-kernel kernel/bzImage \
-append "console=hvc0 root=/dev/vda rw acpi=off reboot=t panic=-1" -m 512 \
-smp 2 \
-device virtio-rng-device \
-netdev user,id=mynet0 \
-device virtio-net-device,netdev=mynet0
```

And here is the output of ifconfig

```
/ # ifconfig -a
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 52:54:00:12:34:56  
          BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          LOOPBACK  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

So far I've tried tried running both Alpine and Ubuntu as the guest OS.
I've tried running the same setup from scratch in a VirtualBox VM, to see if my problem comes from a misconfigured host OS or Qemu install. Both attempts have given the exact same result of a VM that has two network cards without an IP address. And the machine cannot reach localhost or the internet.